# How does an encrypted file system stay reasonably fast?

Tags: filesystem, encryption

I want to encrypt my file system and wondered can my file system stay as fast as it would be without any encryption? If so why, if not how does this affect the read/write operations?

Comment: While the decryption of your data does add compute overhead, I think it is still much faster than the actual disk read